# Angular - Can't unsubscribe() from events

Tags: angular

I've tried to unsubscribe() from events; however, it didn't worked, here is a code snippet:

```
watchMethod(){
  this.watchPosition = this.geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe(resp => {
  let userLatLong = { "lat": resp.coords.latitude, "lng": resp.coords.longitude };
  console.log('is watching')
});
}

stopWatching(){
//on click stop watching the current user location
this.watchPosition.unsubscribe();
}
```

By the way, I didn't get any outputs nor errors. The only thing I see on the console is : `is watching` For some reason, `unsubscribe()` does not work.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: Could you expand on *"didn't worked"*. Errors? Unexpected outputs?

Comment: That's the issue, I didn't receive any errors! No outputs. The only thing is that I see that `watchMethod()` keeps running as the console prints `is watching`

Comment: Then *mention that in the question*, that's part of a [mcve]. You appear to have [asked this twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45654369/3001761), with only minor differences; why?

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited, thanks

Comment: That's still not a working example - when and where do these methods get called? How did you test this behaviour? Nobody else can recreate it from this.

Comment: `watchMethod()` is called once the view is initiated, on the other hand, `stopWatching()` is called once the user request stop watching the location (by clicking on a button on the view)

Comment: **Again**, edit the question. Don't just describe it, *actually write an example*.

Comment: If you add console.log('stopped watching') to your stopWatching function, do you see that output when you click the button that executes that function? Does 'is watching' continue to output to the console after that?

Comment: After adding `console.log('stopped watching')` to `stopWatching` function it shows `stopped watching` however `is watching` continue to output to the console... This turns me crazy, I really don't know what's happening...

Comment: Where are you calling watchMethod from initially? ngOnInit? Or the result of a button click?

Comment: It's the result of a button click

Comment: I've updated my answer - see 'Edit:' at the bottom. This may be an issue with the button click event causing the .subscribe to be executed multiple times. Try that and see if it changes the behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Add these imports to your component

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

Add this in your class - I usually do this above the constructor.

```
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>()
```

Add an ngOnDestroy function

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

And then add this immediately before your .subscribe (you should use this exact syntax before every .subscribe in components with multiples).

```
  .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
```

So in your case, it would look like this.

```
   watchMethod(){
     this.geolocation.watchPosition()
       .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
       .subscribe(resp => {
           let userLatLong = { "lat": resp.coords.latitude, "lng": resp.coords.longitude };
           console.log('is watching')
      });
  }
```

So what happens is the subscribe will remain active until you navigate away from the component, at which point ngOnDestroy fires which unsubscribes from the Observable cleanly.

If you want to manually stop subscribing without leaving the component, you can do this:

```
    stopWatching(){
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
   }
```

Note that you can also remove the overhead of the this.watchPosition instance variable which seems to just be used as a scaffold to hang the .subscribe method on.

EDIT: The only thing I can think is the button click is creating more than one event and it's causing the .subscribe to fire multiple times.

Perhaps in your button, include the $event as a parameter, and then call stopPropagation on the event in your function.

```
<button (click)="watchMethod($event)">Watch Method </button>
```

And update your watchMethod:

```
   watchMethod(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     this.geolocation.watchPosition()
       .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
       .subscribe(resp => {
           let userLatLong = { "lat": resp.coords.latitude, "lng": resp.coords.longitude };
           console.log('is watching')
      });
  }
```

Comment: Could you expand on why - how is this better than unsubscribe?

Comment: You are unsubscribing - takeUntil keeps the .subscribe alive until you terminate it, either by navigating away from the component, in which case ngOnDestroy unsubscribes as part of the component destroy method, or manually in the event you want to stop watching the stream based on a button click. It also removes all the boilerplate overhead of having to define instance variables just to hang your .subscriptions on so you can access the .unsubscribe method.

Comment: But you could just have `this.subscription.unsubscribe()` in the `stopWatching`. That's fewer lines, and still only one "scaffolding" property, and arguably more semantic. What you're suggesting is, if anything, *more* boilerplate, unless you have a whole bunch of subscriptions you want to end at once. Also calling your own things `ng...` is probably not wise. But thanks for adding that to the answer.

Comment: Oh and none of this explains why the OP's current code doesn't work, so potentially doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith, seems that it didn't work too as the event is still running, as suggestions on how to debug it ?

Comment: In my experience, it's common to have multiple subscriptions in a single component, so having a single, repeatable and well defined way to terminate them all when the component is disposed of is desirable. It's also easy to understand, and guarantees that you won't leak memory, doesn't require on garbage collection and prevents difficult to troubleshoot issues where returning to a component results in multiple values appearing as the Observable still has active references to the component.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith subscriptions remain active even after destroying the view, and also it seems that it keeps duplicating the calls each time I open the view where I have the subscription

Comment: By the way, all the subscriptions stops once I refresh the page (which is normal....), the question now is how to have the same with the code as `unsubscribe()` didn't worked ?

Comment: @StephenR.Smith I've done the following : `console.log('watch is : ', this.watchPosition.unsubscribe())` and got `undefined`